# Pass R object name as argument in shell

Tags: r

I'm having a little trouble here using the shell command in R. I have the a java JAR file that takes as input a file containing a character vector (1 tweet per line). I'm calling it from the shell function:

shell("java -Xmx500m -jar C:/Users/User/Documents/R/java/ark-tweet-nlp-0.3.2/ark-tweet-nlp-0.3.2.jar --input-format text C:/Users/User/Documents/R/java/ark-tweet-nlp-0.3.2/examples/test.txt",intern=T)

Rather than pull the character vector from a text file external to the R environment, I want to be able to pass a vector that I have preprocessed within R. For example, if the file "text.txt" is imported into R as a character vector called test, I thought I could do this:

shell(paste("java -Xmx500m -jar C:/Users/User/Documents/R/java/ark-tweet-nlp-0.3.2/ark-tweet-nlp-0.3.2.jar --input-format text",test,sep=" "),intern=T)

But the jar file that is being called needs to actually read the file name, not the file contents. My workaround is to write the preprocessed file to my drive and then reimport using the shell script, but that is clunky and will mess up later processing I plan on doing.

Comment: Sorry DWin, I edited my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the system command set to create an environment variable, then read it from java. The shared location will be the environment variable table.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. In my example, test is the vector name, so for example it could be: test<-c("this","is","my","vector")

Comment: This isn't the solution - if you just run the paste section of your script, you will get the "java-Xmx500m... test". What I need is "java-Xmx500m...y". I need to be able to pass the named object to the java script. Java I don't think is really the issue here - I think the real question is how do you pass a named R object to shell/cmd prompt. This thread (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-September/113680.html) says there is no overlap
between the R object name space and the Windows object name space, though it's not quite the same situation. Maybe I have to deal with external files.